# How to recursive loop g:each in a table model

Tags: loops, grails

String title

String parent

```
       id  |  title  |  parent  |
       1   | Clothes |     0    |
       2   |   Men   |     1    | 
       3   |  Shoes  |     2    |
       4   |  Adidas |     3    |
```

how can i recursive loop in this situation
i need this
clothes
-men
--shoes
---Adidas
----may be too long

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Implement a taglib method that takes care of the complex logic and outputs some (preferably simple) HTML that is **reusable**.

First let's define a simple Node for demo purposes:

```
class Node {
    String title
    List<Node> children

    public boolean hasChildren() {
        return children as Boolean
    }
}
```

Define the whole "product tree":

```
def rootNodeDemo = new Node(title: 'clothes', children: [
    new Node(title:'men', children: [
        new Node(title: 'shoes', children: [
            new Node(title: 'adidas')
        ])
    ]),
    new Node(title: 'women', children: [
        new Node(title: 'shoes', children: [
            new Node(title: 'adidas')
        ])
    ])
])
```

Here's the taglib:

```
class NavigationTaglib {
    static namespace = "navigation"

    /**
     * @param rootNode - the root node from where to start rendering.
     */
    def productCategoryTree = { attrs, body ->
        def rootNode = attrs?.remove('rootNode') // this is the clothes -root node or maybe even the root of everything (which probably needs to be omitted in HTML-rendering)

        if(!rootNode) {
            return
        }

        out << renderTreeHtml(rootNode).toString()
    }

    private StringBuilder renderTreeHtml(Node rootNode) {
        StringBuilder treeHtml = new StringBuilder()

        treeHtml << """<ul class="navi node-level-1">"""

        treeHtml << renderTreeHtmlItems(rootNode, 2)

        treeHtml << "</ul>"
    }

    private StringBuilder renderTreeHtmlItems(Node node, int level) {
        StringBuilder treeHtml = new StringBuilder()

        treeHtml << """<li>${node.title?.encodeAsHTML()}"""

        if(node.hasChildren()) {
            treeHtml << """<ul class="node-level-${level}">"""

            node.children.each { Node child ->
                treeHtml << renderTreeHtmlItems(child, level+1)
            }

            treeHtml << "</ul>"
        }

        treeHtml << "</li>"
    }
}
```

In GSP (we assume that model has an entry named rootNodeDemo, which has the contents of rootNodeDemo defined earlier):

```
<navigation:productCategoryTree rootNode="${rootNodeDemo}" />
```

This will produce the following HTML, sorry, no pretty prints like new lines or tabs :(

```
<ul class="navi node-level-1"><li>clothes<ul class="node-level-2"><li>men<ul class="node-level-3"><li>shoes<ul class="node-level-4"><li>adidas</li></ul></li></ul></li><li>women<ul class="node-level-3"><li>shoes<ul class="node-level-4"><li>adidas</li></ul></li></ul></li></ul></li></ul>
```

Which, when rendered in a web browser, looks like something that's in the following JS-fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/bq4wkyc3/

Comment: If the tree is a big one, then it could be beneficial to render directly to **out** instead of appending it all in the *StringBuilder*..